# UIView анимация

Tags: анимация, ios

Всем привет.

Есть вид, который с помощью анимации выплывает из-за экрана. На нем кнопки, которые должны двигаться вместе с этим видом. Собственно, как сделать эти кнопки?

Вид анимирую следующим образом. Есть переменная draw, если она ==1, то вид убирается, если 0, то вид выплывает обратно на экран. При нажатии на определенную кнопку происходит:

```
[UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0];
myView.frame=CGRectMake(menu_x,menu_y,menu_width,menu_height-150*draw);
[UIView commitAnimations];

draw=!draw
```

При анимации вида кнопки остаются на месте. А как их заставить двигаться вместе с видом?

Comment: @Troir, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Где кнопки лежат? Если лежат на виде, то и двигаться с ним будут. А вообще `UIView beginAnimations` и его присные считаются устаревшими, хотя и не запрещенными аж с выхода 4.0, более правильно использовать блоки (группа методов `animateWithDuration:animations`:)

**UPD:**

Если кнопки лежат на виде, меняется размер вида и кнопки должны на нем переместиться то вам надо либо добавить в анимацию (перед `[UIView commitAnimations];`) еще изменение их положения, либо же добавить введенный в 6.0 механизм [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html), который вполне способен задать для ваших кнопок относительное положение, например, привязав их к низу вида. Кроме того заходит ли вид под бар и просвечивает ли если заходит, по-моему, тоже настраивается, но на вскидку не помню как, а искать сейчас некогда

Comment: Кнопки лежат на виде, и они перемещаются с видом если перемещать вид, соответственно. Я же его изменяю по высоте - а таким образом кнопки никак не реагируют на изменение вида. 

А изменяю я вид по высоте, а не по координате по следующей причине:
Вид выплывает сверху экрана, а там есть Navigation bar. Если именно перемещать вид, то он заходит за бар и как бы "просвечивает" сквозь него.

Comment: обновил ответ, вы бы сразу написали что меняете размер, из вашего кода это не очевидно поскольку я понятия не имею каким рект был изначально